# How can we put the big observation in same order with same spaces and lines in the word

Tags: sas

Can anyone help me out please?

I have following data set:

```
    data have;
    id    name country 
    100   abc   ind
```

just for understanding clearly, 4th column is comments, I am adding below

```
comments:
"SWIFTT LIST BRUPI
ACTION REQUIRED: REASSESS ASUP TO PICKUP INCM
Refer to note dated 21/07/2016 entered by TDEMP003.
ACTION TAKEN:  I have reassessed Asupp based on the income from 25/07/2016. Asupp rate is now $69.00 ($34.50 each).
Outcome of call to client No
Letter sent: Yes

Client Number                                                                       357-208-501 
Entitlement Date                                                                25/07/2016  

Gross SA                                                             $-   
Gross Wages                                                          $823.31 
Extra Income from Assets                                         $-   
TOTAL GROSS INCOME                                               $823.31
```

so there are 4 columns.

i want the result in word like this;

```
        id 100
      name abc
   country ind
  comments "SWIFTT LIST BRUPI
            ACTION REQUIRED: REASSESS ASUP TO PICKUP INCM
            Refer to note dated 21/07/2016 entered by TDEMP003.
            ACTION TAKEN:  I have reassessed Asupp based on the income  
            25/07/2016. Asupp rate is now $69.00 ($34.50 each).
            Outcome of call to client No
            Letter sent: Yes

            Client number 12345

            Entitlement 
            Date 25/07/2016                                                     

            Gross SA                                                             
            Gross Wages                                                             $823.31 
             Extra Income from Assets                                            $-   
           TOTAL GROSS INCOME                                            $823.31
```

I tried with following code:

```
data _null_;
set client_details;

file " &WORK_DIR_PATH/&filename..doc" noprint lrecl=1200 print;
       put 'ID' @ 30 id /;
       put 'Client name' @30 Name /;
       put 'country' @30 country /;
       put 'comments' @30 comments ;
;
run;
```

I am looking here for 'comments' field (4th column). i could not arrange them in order exactly that shows in the  field. my reuslts are looking ugly. I mean the words and numbers are not showing in same order as in the table. so can anyone please tell how to write that big observation into multiple lines  or exctly how it is showing the row.

Answer (score 0):

One way of doing this is to define a maximum line length via `lrecl` and set the `flowover` option on the `file` statement, e.g.:

```
/*Create file with long line that we want to split across 2 lines*/
data _null_;
    file "%sysfunc(pathname(work))/test.text" lrecl = 10 flowover;
    put '01234567890123456789';
run;

/*Check that we get 2 lines*/
data _null_;
    infile "%sysfunc(pathname(work))/test.text";
    input;
    put _INFILE_;
run;
```

N.B. setting `lrecl` will cap the length of *all* lines in the output file, not just the lines where you're printing your really long variable. If this isn't what you want then an alternative option would be to chop it up into substrings and print those one at a time.